# Styling not applied with Vue 3 Custom Elements

Tags: vue.js, custom-element

I'm using Vue 3, options api.

I have a couple of components made in vue.

I have a main-component and this uses different other components (like baseInput, baseRadio, etc).

When I load the main-component into my html, the styling in the main-component is loaded, but styling defined in the other linked components is not applied.

How can I get the styling for the deeper components to also be applied, when using vue as custom elements?

I tried to set styling globally, but it gets scoped to the main-component

```
index.html
   |
   |- main-component.ce.vue
             |
             |- baseInput.vue
```

main.js

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue';

import VueMainComponent from './components/main-component.ce.vue';

const MainComponent = defineCustomElement(VueMainComponent );

customElements.define('main-component', MainComponent );
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `defineCustomElement`? Can you share the contents of your SFCs? (I guess the styles are defined in these files)

Comment: I use defineCustomElement because I'm using the components in an older existing website. The place where it is used, have other html, and a 'normal' vue app is not sufficient. 

Custom Elements looked like a valid option, but it seems this is the major issue with it at the moment.

https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4662